# Finding uncommon rows from two data frames, each having multiple non unique rows

Tags: r

Finding uncommon rows from two data frames, each having multiple non-unique rows, each being matched once. For more explanation about the problem, refer the below image
[Explanation and desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S2dZ.jpg)

```
df1<-data.frame("ID"=c("123","124","123"), "Amt"=c("57365","57365","57365"))
df2<-data.frame("ID"=c("123"), "Amt"=c("57365"))
```

Comment: Do you need `df1[!duplicated(df1),]`

Answer (score 0):

We can do a `join` with `data.table`

```
unique(setDT(df1)[df1[df2, .I, on = .(ID)]])
#    ID   Amt
#1: 123 57365
#2: 124 57365
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

df1<-data.frame("ID"=c("123","124","123"), "Amt"=c("57365","57365","57365"))
df2<-data.frame("ID"=c("123"), "Amt"=c("57365"))

df3 <- df1 %>%
  inner_join(df2, by="ID") %>%
  distinct()
```

This just returns row1 of df1. I hope that's useful.

Comment: This gives intersection. OP is looking for uncommon rows not common.